# como mostrar o resultado de uma sql em <section> diferentes?

Tags: php, html, sql

Como faço para que os projetos pertencentes ao mesmo departamento fiquem na mesma section?

```html
    $sql = "SELECT d.nome, p.titulo FROM projeto p, departamento d WHERE p.dpto_id=d.id ORDER BY d.nome, p.titulo";

    $dpto=null;
    foreach ($rows as $reg){

    $departamento=$reg["nome"];
        $titulo=$reg["titulo"];

        if($departamento!==$dpto){
    echo  "<section>";
        echo "<h1>". $departamento . "</h1>";
        echo "<p>". $titulo ."</p>";
      } elseif ($departamento===$dpto) {
        echo "<p>". $titulo ."</p>";
      }

        $dpto=$departamento;
     }
     
    //Resultdo final deveria ser assim
    <section>
      <h1>nome do departamento</h1>
      <p>lista de projetos</p> 
    </section>

    <section>
      <h1>outro departamento</h1>
      <p>sua de projetos</p>
    </section>
```

Tentei assim, mas não consigo fechar a tag section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz dessa forma:

```
$dpto=null;
foreach ($rows as $reg){

    $departamento=$reg["nome"];
    $titulo=$reg["titulo"];

    if($departamento!==$dpto){
echo  "<section>";
    echo "<h1>". $departamento . "</h1>";
    echo "<p>". $titulo ."</p>";
echo  "</section>";
  } elseif ($departamento===$dpto) {
echo  "<section>";
    echo "<p>". $titulo ."</p>";
echo  "</section>";
  }
    $dpto=$departamento;
 }
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Os projetos FV e DS pertencem ao Dpto1, mas ficaram fora da seção. O mesmo ocorreu com os projetos ABGO e GT do Dpto2.  

section
h1 dto1 h1
XTZ
section

FV
DS

section
h1 dto2 h1
RT
section

ABGO
GT

section
h1 dto3 h1
YWZ
section

section
h1 dto4 h1
QWE
section

Comment: Eu atualizei o programa, tenta desse novo jeito

Answer (score 0):

Você terá que ter um loop aninhado dentro de outro, algo do tipo:

```
foreach($departamentos as $departamento):
 $produtos = SQL ///SELECT * FROM PRODUTOS WHERE idDepartamento = $departamento->id // sua consulta aqui.
 foreach($produtos as $produto):
  echo $produto->nome."<br>";
 endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Desta forma você poderá selecionar todos os produtos em cada interação de departamento.